# What should I do with default menu items in MainMenu in the new Cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, human-interface

When you create new Cocoa application Xcode generates MainMenu.xib for you with the sets of predefined menu items (File, Edit, Format, View, etc.).

I make a very simple application. I really don't need menu items Edit, Format, View. What is the best practice in this case. Should I remove or keep them? It's look very strange for me that so simple application has so detailed main menu with a lot of disabled items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not relevant to your application I'd remove them, although if your application involves any text I would keep the Edit menu for Copy/Paste.